# kwargs for linestyle and linecolour within the axvline and axhline with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a vertical line at the axis position x=1 with `'-.k'` linestyle. I tried the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.axvline(x=1, ymin=0, ymax=0.35, '-.k')
```

But it returns the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-70-04f296edd639>", line 7
    plt.axvline(x=1,ymin=0,ymax=0.35, '-.k')
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

What is the correct way to specify the linestyle `kwarg` in this situation ?

Answer (score 27):

Is an image worth many words?

[image]

After the demonstrative image, I'd like to add that
`matplotlib.pyplot.axvline` is a thin wrapper around `matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline`, documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html).

The `Axes.axvline` method supports a large number of keyword arguments, of all of them two, as you have seen, are relevant to your question:

1. `color=...`, the `color` argument is documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_color) and
2. `linestyle=...`, the `linestyle` argument is documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle)

To exemplify

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot((0,1,2,3))
plt.axvline(2, color='k', linestyle='--')
```

The keyword arguments here discussed of course apply also to the `axhline` method.